# Overriding Application_PostAuthenticateRequest method

Tags: c#, authentication, model-view-controller, methods, overriding

Cannot convert type of the result I get when trying to get the 'TitreStatutPersonne' in string when joining two tables (Personnes, IdStatutPersonne)

Here's the method

```
    protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FormsAuthentication.CookiesSupported == true)
        {
            if (Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    //let us take out the username now                
                    string login = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value).Name;
                    string titre = string.Empty;

                    using (AgendaContext db = new AgendaContext())
                    {

                        Personne personne = db.Personnes.SingleOrDefault(p => p.LoginPersonne == login);
                        titre = (from s in db.StatutsPersonne join p in db.Personnes on s.IdStatutPersonne equals p.IdStatutPersonne select new {s.TitreStatutPersonne}).Distinct().ToString();
                    }
                    //let us extract the roles from our own custom cookie


                    //Let us set the Pricipal with our user specific details
                    HttpContext.Current.User = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(
                      new System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity(login, "Forms"), titre.Split(';'));
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    //something went wrong
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

probably you need to correct line:

```
titre = (from s in db.StatutsPersonne join p in db.Personnes on s.IdStatutPersonne equals p.IdStatutPersonne select s.TitreStatutPersonne).FirstOrDefault();
```

because you trying to convert to string anonimous type object at new {s.TitreStatutPersonne}

Comment: Thanks no error but I got a problem, [Authorize(Roles="Administrateur")] doesn't work even tough I got an Administrateur in my StatutPersonne Table with the field TitreStatutPersonne

Comment: I know where my mistake is but can't correct it. I have to delete the line Personne personne = db.Personne etc... and do something like titre = (from s in db.StatutsPersonne join p in db.Personnes on s.IdStatutPersonne equals p.IdStatutPersonne select s.TitreStatutPersonne).FirstOrDefault() WHERE p=> p.LoginPersonne = login

Comment: Got it!
titre = (from s in db.StatutsPersonne join p in db.Personnes on s.IdStatutPersonne equals p.IdStatutPersonne where p.LoginPersonne == login select s.TitreStatutPersonne).FirstOrDefault();